# mysql Column not found loop

Tags: java, mysql

Hi have a method that creates a LinkedList of compMac object. CompMac object contain elements from a mysql table row. Each row contain a nickname and a location so I use a loop to create a 'compMac' for each row and add them in the linkedlist. I don't know why, but the first 'compMac' is created and is being added to the linkedlist, but after that I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'nickname' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5729)
at server.DbConnect.getArray(DbConnect.java:224)
at server.doComms.sendArray(doComms.java:127)
at server.doComms.whileChatting(doComms.java:107)
at server.doComms.run(doComms.java:32)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Here is my method:

```
public LinkedList<compMac> getArray()
{
    LinkedList<compMac> locArray = new LinkedList<compMac>();
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM online";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nn = rs.getString("nickname");
            String loc = rs.getString("location");//mac addresses
            String cX=getCoorX(loc);
            String cY=getCoorY(loc);
            String building=getBuilding(loc);
            String floor=getFloor(loc);

            locArray.add(new compMac(nn,loc,cX,cY,building,floor));

            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return locArray;

}
```

But I do have a nickname column, I like I said, the first compMac is created, when I pop the linkedlist I get the first row's informations.

Thanks to anyone having an idea whats wrong with my code.

EDIT: Here the class code:
      package server;
      import java.sql.*;
      import java.util.LinkedList;

```
  import com.example.client.Mac;
  import com.example.client.compMac;


  public class DbConnect {

private Connection con;
private Statement st;
private Statement stClean;
private ResultSet rs;

public DbConnect(){

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://melucio.no-ip.biz:3306/TOC","XXXXX","XXXXXXX");
        st = con.createStatement();
        stClean = con.createStatement();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
}






/*This method returns the x coor. of mac address*/
    public String getCoorX(String mac){
    String cX = "";
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                return rs.getString("coorX");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return cX;

}

    /*This method returns the y coor. of mac address*/
    public String getCoorY(String mac){
    String cY = "";
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                return rs.getString("coorY");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return cY;

}   public String getBuilding(String mac){
        String buil = "";
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                    return rs.getString("building");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return buil;

    }

    public String getFloor(String mac){
        String fl = "";
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                    return rs.getString("floor");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return fl;

    }



/*Update the location table*/
public void updateLocation(String userNN,String location){//,long time){

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(!isOnline(userNN))
    {System.out.println("not online");
        setOnline(userNN,location);}
    else{
        try{
            //String query ="UPDATE online SET location = '" +location +"' WHERE nickname='" +userNN +"'";
            String query ="UPDATE online SET location = '" +location +"', lastSeen = "+time +"  WHERE nickname='" +userNN +"'";

            st.executeUpdate(query);

        }   
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("ayayaya");}  
    }
}


public LinkedList<compMac> getArray()
{
    LinkedList<compMac> locArray = new LinkedList<compMac>();
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM online";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nn = rs.getString("nickname");
            String loc = rs.getString("location");//mac addresses
            String cX=getCoorX(loc);
            String cY=getCoorY(loc);
            String building=getBuilding(loc);
            String floor=getFloor(loc);

            locArray.add(new compMac(nn,loc,cX,cY,building,floor));

            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return locArray;

}

public void clean()
{
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long acceptableTime = currentTime-120000;
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM online";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nn = rs.getString("nickname");
            Long ls = rs.getLong("lastSeen");
            if(ls<acceptableTime)//{}
            {stClean.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM online WHERE     nickname='"+nn+"'");} 

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

}

Comment: I would believe the error mentioned. Are you connecting to right DB? To confirm, is nickname column available in ONLINE table?

Comment: yes, and its working for the first loop iteration... :S I really don't know whats wrong. The returned linkedlist contains one element containing the information of the first row of the online table

Comment: how have you initialized the Statement object?

Comment: In the class constructor

Comment: Can you share that code as well? Is the statement object being reused for different query? where are you closing the statement? What is the datatype of nickname?

Comment: Here is the code, I didnt include a couple of method but all the methods related to the problem are there.Nickname datatype is VARCHAR. I think it might be the fact that I call getCoorX and getCoorY?! Usign the statement in different method at the same time?! Im really new to mysql..

Comment: Did the answer given below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you are reusing the same Statement object in different methods. So after the first iteration the last method getFloor changes the st object to query on coordinate table. I suggest you initialize separate Statement objects in every method and close it in finally block.

```
   import com.example.client.Mac;
  import com.example.client.compMac;


  public class DbConnect {

private Connection con;

public DbConnect(){

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://melucio.no-ip.biz:3306/TOC","XXXXX","XXXXXXX");


    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
}






/*This method returns the x coor. of mac address*/
    public String getCoorX(String mac){
    String cX = "";
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                return rs.getString("coorX");
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

    return cX;

}

    /*This method returns the y coor. of mac address*/
    public String getCoorY(String mac){
    String cY = "";
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                return rs.getString("coorY");
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    return cY;

}   public String getBuilding(String mac){
        String buil = "";
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                    return rs.getString("building");
                }
            }
        rs.close();
        st.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return buil;

    }

    public String getFloor(String mac){
        String fl = "";
        try{
            String query = "SELECT * FROM coordinate";
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("mac").equals(mac)){
                    return rs.getString("floor");
                }
            }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
      }
        catch(Exception e){}
        return fl;

    }



/*Update the location table*/
public void updateLocation(String userNN,String location){//,long time){

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(!isOnline(userNN))
    {System.out.println("not online");
        setOnline(userNN,location);}
    else{
        try{
            //String query ="UPDATE online SET location = '" +location +"' WHERE nickname='" +userNN +"'";
            String query ="UPDATE online SET location = '" +location +"', lastSeen = "+time +"  WHERE nickname='" +userNN +"'";

            st.executeUpdate(query);

        }   
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("ayayaya");}  
    }
}


public LinkedList<compMac> getArray()
{
    LinkedList<compMac> locArray = new LinkedList<compMac>();
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM online";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nn = rs.getString("nickname");
            String loc = rs.getString("location");//mac addresses
            String cX=getCoorX(loc);
            String cY=getCoorY(loc);
            String building=getBuilding(loc);
            String floor=getFloor(loc);

            locArray.add(new compMac(nn,loc,cX,cY,building,floor));

            }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
  }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    return locArray;

}

public void clean()
{
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long acceptableTime = currentTime-120000;
    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM online";
        Statement st = con.createStatement(); 
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            String nn = rs.getString("nickname");
            Long ls = rs.getLong("lastSeen");
            if(ls<acceptableTime)//{}
            {stClean.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM online WHERE     nickname='"+nn+"'");} 

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}
```